# Bar chart is stacking except in one specific instance and I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am making a bar graph for a reservation system. The blue bars represent reservations in the database while the green bar represents the reservation the user is trying to make. The blue bars('other reservations') populate fine. The green bar('this reservation') populates fine. The issue is I keep getting duplicates in my labels field in my x axis and I'm not sure why.

[labels duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfd4z.png)

[When they share a stack, labels get duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjDkA.png)

[same as image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A12HY.png)

[Another bug I encountered but only when the last slot interacts with the first slot. ie. 'thisreservation' is for 800-900 and 'otherreservation' starts at 900. Here it just straight up duplicates and wont stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yqkq.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var storedReservations = [];

  $("#popoutButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected restaurant ID
    var selectedRestaurantID = document.getElementById("RestaurantID").value;

    // Get the selected date and time
    var selectedDateTime = document.getElementById("dateTimePicker").value;

    // Make an AJAX request to retrieve the reservation information
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Reservations/GetReservationsByDate",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
        restaurantID: selectedRestaurantID,
        date: selectedDateTime,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        // Process the response and display the reservation information
        var reservations = response.reservations;

        reservations.forEach(function (reservation) {
          var arrivalTime = reservation.arrivalTime;
          var slots = reservation.slots;
          var pax = reservation.pax;

          // Store each reservation as an object in the storedReservations array
          storedReservations.push({
            arrivalTime: arrivalTime,
            slots: slots,
            pax: pax,
          });

          // Display the reservation information as desired
          console.log("Arrival Time: " + arrivalTime);
          console.log("Slots: " + slots);
          console.log("Pax: " + pax);
        });
        // Use the storedReservations array for further processing or storage
        console.log(storedReservations);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle the error if the AJAX request fails
        console.log("Error:", error);
      },
    });

    // Get the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById("availabilityChart").getContext("2d");

    // Get the selected date from Reservation.ArrivalDateTime field
    var selectedDate = new Date(
      $("#dateTimePicker").val()
    ).toLocaleDateString();

    // Update the selectedDate span element with the selected date
    $("#selectedDate").text(selectedDate);

    // Get the arrival time from the input field
    var arrivalDateTime = $("#dateTimePicker").val();
    var arrivalTime = new Date(arrivalDateTime).toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      hour12: true,
    });

    // Get the reserved seats value from the span element
    var reservedSeats = parseInt($("#reservedSeats").text());

    // Get the pax value from the input field
    var pax = parseInt($("#pax").val());

    // Get the slot value from the input field
    var slots = parseInt($("#Slots").val());

    // Calculate the maximum value for scaling the y-axis
    var maxValue = reservedSeats + 50;

    // Update the labels array with the arrivalTime
    var labels = fillChartLabels(arrivalTime, pax, slots);

    var dataset1 = {
      label: "This Reservation",
      data: labels.map(function (label, index) {
        if (
          index >= labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) &&
          index - labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) < slots
        ) {
          return pax;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }),
      backgroundColor: labels.map(function (label, index) {
        if (
          index >= labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) &&
          index - labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) < slots
        ) {
          if (pax > reservedSeats) {
            return "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)"; // Red color for bar if pax exceeds reserved seats or the maximum value
          } else {
            return "rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.6)"; // Green color for other bars in dataset1
          }
        } else {
          return "rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.6)"; // Use the same dark green color for all other bars in dataset1
        }
      }),
      borderWidth: 1,
      stack: "stacked",
    };

    // Generate data for dataset2 using storedReservations array
    var dataset2 = {
      label: "Other Reservations",
      data: labels.map(function (label, index) {
        var count = 0;

        storedReservations.forEach(function (reservation) {
          var arrivalTime = reservation.arrivalTime;
          var slots = reservation.slots;
          var pax = reservation.pax;

          // Convert the arrivalTime to 12-hour format for comparison
          var formattedArrivalTime = new Date(arrivalTime).toLocaleTimeString(
            [],
            {
              hour: "numeric",
              minute: "2-digit",
              hour12: true,
            }
          );

          if (
            index >= labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) &&
            index - labels.indexOf(arrivalTime) < slots
          ) {
            count += pax;
          }
        });

        return count;
      }),
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6)", // Blue color for dataset2
      borderWidth: 1,
      stack: "stacked",
    };

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [dataset1, dataset2],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Time", // X-axis label
            },
          },
          y: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Available Spots", // Y-axis label
            },
            beginAtZero: true,
            max: maxValue, // Set the maximum value for the y-axis
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              label: function (context) {
                var label = context.dataset.label || "";
                if (label) {
                  label += ": ";
                }
                label += context.parsed.y;
                return label;
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });

    // Find the index of the arrival time in the labels array
    var arrivalIndex = labels.indexOf(arrivalTime);
    if (arrivalIndex !== -1) {
      // Update the data array with the pax value for the arrivalIndex and subsequent slots
      for (var i = arrivalIndex; i < arrivalIndex + slots; i++) {
        if (i < labels.length) {
          chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = pax;
        }
      }

      // Highlight the bars representing the arrival time and subsequent slots
      for (var j = arrivalIndex; j < arrivalIndex + slots; j++) {
        if (j < labels.length) {
          chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[j] = backgroundColors[j];
        }
      }

      chart.update();

      //Open Modal
      $("#popoutModal").modal("show");
    }
  });
});

function fillChartLabels(arrivalTime, pax, slots) {
  var labels = [
    "10:00 AM",
    "10:30 AM",
    "11:00 AM",
    "11:30 AM",
    "12:00 PM",
    "12:30 PM",
    "01:00 PM",
    "01:30 PM",
    "02:00 PM",
    "02:30 PM",
    "03:00 PM",
    "03:30 PM",
    "04:00 PM",
    "04:30 PM",
    "05:00 PM",
    "05:30 PM",
    "06:00 PM",
    "06:30 PM",
    "07:00 PM",
    "07:30 PM",
    "08:00 PM",
    "08:30 PM",
    "09:00 PM",
    "09:30 PM",
    "10:00 PM",
    "10:30 PM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "11:30 PM",
  ];

  var arrivalIndex = labels.indexOf(arrivalTime);

  for (var i = 1; i <= slots; i++) {
    var index = (arrivalIndex + i) % labels.length;
    labels.splice(index, 0, labels[index]);
  }

  return labels;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!